# How to convert all type of file into .swf format using php on Linux

Tags: php, file-conversion

As I Upload the file using `php`, it should move to conversion tools and the output, i.e. a file in a `*.swf` format, should be uploaded to the same directory, where my original file exists and should be displayed in my website.

I have searched long and I got `swftool`, but it's not working on my linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Converting every format is not possible. Your lazy question is a bit broad there.

As alternative to `swftool` you can however utilize OpenOffice/LibreOffice. The Impress presentation module allows to export `.swf` animations. LibreOffice can be utilized from the commandline (thus via php).

```
soffice -headless -convert-to swf animation.ppt
```

You can google other examples.

The actual task then becomes to create a Powerpoint or Impress document first (it's an XML format) from whatever input and media files you have. (Maybe a simple .SMIL works too.)

Answer (score 0):

You still can convert **any** document to SWF if it can be printed. As almost any kind of document can be printed, it is possible to convert them to SWF. In order to achieve this you need to use a virtual SWF printer software, e.g. Print2Flash (www.print2flash.com). The PHP code is quite simple:

```
$p2f = new COM("Print2Flash4.Server2");
$p2f->ConvertFile($sourcefile,$outfile);
```

$sourcefile is the path and name of the source document, e.g. a PDF or Office document. $outfile is the name of the output SWF file. more details can be got from php sample from the SDK that can be downloaded from http://print2flash.com/download.php